Mulesoft Mule 4 Error Handling - where are the headers?
...inside the error handler for a Mule 4 application, I want to examine the response headers from a failed HTTP request. (in particular, I want to get the values in x-headers returned by a rate limiting policy.)
The problem is that when the Mule Event gets to the error handler scope, the attributes are no longer visible. #[attributes] returns null
In the past I remember doing something like:
#[error.muleMessage.typedAttributes.headers."x-ratelimit-reset]

When I try this today, I get an exception that indicates that "muleMessage" is scoped "private final"
What can we do to examine the remains of a failed HTTP request during execution of the error handler?

It turns out that the answer is within #[error.errorMessage]
In that structure, the attributes and the payload at the time of the error can be seen.
So the proper expression to examine that header would be:
#[error.errorMessage.attributes.headers."x-ratelimit-reset"]

Try it in your logger from the error handler and see what you get!

The expression #[error.muleMessage] was an undocumented way to access error details that stopped working since Mule 4.6. That's the risk of relying on undocumented implementation details. They can stop working because of other changes.
The documented way to access error details is #[error.errorMessage].
